# Can the config crate merge environment variables into a subsection of a hierarchical config file?

Tags: rust

I am using the [Config crate](https://docs.rs/config/0.10.1/config/index.html) in Rust, and would like to use environment variables to set keys *inside* a section of the config. The end goal is to override application settings from a docker compose file, or docker command line, using the environment.

If my config was the following, could I use a specifically crafted environment variable to set `database.echo` ?

*(code blurb below is taken from [this example](https://github.com/mehcode/config-rs/blob/master/examples/hierarchical-env/config/development.toml))*

```
debug = true

[database]
echo = true
```

The [example code](https://github.com/mehcode/config-rs/blob/master/examples/hierarchical-env/src/settings.rs) to configure this using the environment variables illustrates only to set keys at the top level. Wondering how to extend this. The `.set()` takes a hierarchical key, so I'm hopeful that there's a way to encode the path in the env variable name.

Comment: The [hierarchical-env](https://github.com/mehcode/config-rs/tree/master/examples/hierarchical-env) example seems to be exactly what you want; specifically `with_prefix("app")`. Since you looked at the examples before asking this question, what's not correct with this one?

Comment: If I had the environment variable `APP_DATABASE_ECHO=true` combined with `with_prefix("app")`, it would set a key at the top level called `database_echo`. I want to set key `echo` inside the database section, rather.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question.

I just noticed that the [Environment](https://docs.rs/config/0.10.1/src/config/env.rs.html#108) code accepts a custom separator which will get replaced with `.` (dot).

So one can set the separator to something like `_XX_` and that would get mapped to a ".". Setting `DATABASE_XX_ECHO=true`, for instance would then change the `database.echo` key.